# Blow up $\{x_1^4+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=0\}\subset\mathbb{C}^4$ twice at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, blowup

I know the definition of the blow up at a point, but have only computed extremely easy cases. I'm reading a paper where the variety
$$x_1^4+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=0$$
is blown up twice at the origin. Now I tried to compute what this would look like, but to be honest I have no real idea what to do here. So according to my definition the blow up we would get the variety
$$
\begin{equation*}
V(x_1y_2=x_2y_1,\\
x_1y_3=x_3y_1,\\
x_1y_4=x_4y_1,\\
x_2y_3=x_3y_2,\\
x_2y_4=x_4y_2,\\
x_3y_4=x_4y_3,\\
x_1^4+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=0
)
\end{equation*}\subset \mathbb{C}^4\times \mathbb{P}^3$$
But now what? This seem quite ugly and unworkable to me. And Now To be honest I don't even know what it would mean to blow up the 'origin' here again, since I don't know what the origin in $\mathbb{C}^4\times \mathbb{P}^3$ is?

It would be much appreciated if someone could work out this computation in some detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blow-up as a subscheme of $\mathbb{C}^4\times \mathbb{P}^3$ comes with standard affine charts, which are where one of the co-ordinates $y_j$ is non-zero. You can work this out for each $j$, but here the interesting case is $j=1$. Then the blow-up formulae that you wrote down say $$x_i = x_1 (y_i y_1^{-1}),$$ where $x_1$ and the $y_i y_1^{-1}$ are affine co-ordinates on this chart. Putting this into the equation of the hypersurface singularity gives $$0 = x_1^4 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = x_1^4 + x_1^2 (y_2 y_1^{-1})^2 + x_1^2 (y_3 y_1^{-1})^2 + x_1^2 (y_4 y_1^{-1})^2  = x_1^2 ( x_1^2 + (y_2 y_1^{-1})^2 + (y_3 y_1^{-1})^2 + (y_4 y_1^{-1})^2).$$ If we write say $z_i = y_i y_1^{-1},$ this equation is $$x_1^2(x_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 + z_4^2) = 0.$$ In this chart, the exceptional divisor is the locus of $x_1 = 0$ (because if $x_1 = 0$ then all $x_i = x_1 (y_i y_1^{-1})$ are zero too, so the whole hyperplane $x_1 = 0$ maps to the origin in $\mathbb{C}^3$), and the proper transform of our hypersurface singularity is $$x_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 + z_4^2 = 0.$$ That's the result of one blow-up, in this chart. You see that the thing is still singular at the origin, meaning the point $x_1 = z_2 = z_3 = z_4 = 0$. If you do another blow-up, the result looks the same in each affine chart; the proper transform is $$1 + w_2^2 + w_3^2 + w_4^2 = 0,$$ say. You might want to check that if you look at the other standard charts of the blow-up of the singularity we started with, $x_1^4 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 0$, the result is non-singular at the origin. (You should get some equation like $w^2 ( x^4 w^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 1) = 0$ for the total transform in the other charts.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. A couple of things I still don't quite get though. Most importantly, I still don't get the iterated blow up at the origin. Are you saying that in the second blow up we only perform the blow up in the chart $y_1\not=0$? Because we have $4$ 'origins', one in every chart. But for blowing up we need to chose one of these origins. The result will then only be a blow up of the affine part we chose, not of the whole blown up variety right?

Comment: Blowing up a point in an affine chart gives you a piece of the blow-up of the whole thing. The author is speaking of two maps, $X_2 \to X_1 \to X = (x_1^4 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2=0),$ where $X_1\to X$ and $X_2 \to X_1$ are both blow-ups at a single point. Which point is blown up in the map $X_2 \to X_1$ the author does not say precisely but has the reader infer. Here, $X$ is singular at one point, and the blow-up $X_1$ also is singular at one point, which is the origin of one of the standard affine charts. The author might say instead, "blow-up the singular point twice," with the same meaning.

Comment: Oke, but if we blow up a point in one chart, what will it look like in the other charts? I get that away from the blown up point the blow up will be isomorphic to the original variety, but I'd still like to know how we can explicitly write down the blow up in another chart.